# NSFastEnumeration for class members

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, nsfastenumeration

How do I implement NSFastEnumeration for my custom class which returns an enumeration of all class member variables?

```
@interface Employee : NSObject

@property (atomic, copy) NSString * name;
@property (atomic, copy) NSString * designation;
@property (atomic, assign) NSInteger * empID;


@end
```

I am trying to export this data to csv using CHCSVParser (https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser). How do I invoke writeLineOfFields on an array of Employee class objects?

Comment: Share some code, what you have tried so far.

Comment: "How do I invoke writeLineOfFields on an array" An array _already_ implements NSFastEnumeration.